# A way to track latest interactions with the contract?

Tags: transactions

I need a function which will track latest interactions with my contract on the server side. So let's say something like getRecentTransactions() which will return transaction hashes of interactions with the contract in the last 5 minutes. Any API or anything that can help in this case? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`web3.eth.subscribe`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe) from web3js library if you're using JavaScript.

If you're using Python, you can use web3.py's [filtering methods](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#).

I have previously used both, and they both work like charm.